# Pandas Dataframe not able to store decimal values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to store values that can have values upto 5 decimal point value but pandas is storing them all as 0. A piece of code to perform can be found below where GDF is an empty dataframe with row name 'A' and i am trying to place in a value at a particular cell in row A where the word Cl is located. Please help

```
GDF.at['A',Cl]=0.0012
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to assign a decimal to a type int cell. Make sure you are aware of the types in the dataframe you are using.  Also, you should consider moving to `.loc` instead of `.at`.

Consider the following example with it's output showing the difference in dtype and a difference between `.at` and `.loc`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':[0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['B'])
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
df.at['B','A'] = .0012
print(df)
df=df*1000
print(df)
print('__1___')
df.at['B','A']= df.at['B','A'].astype(float)
df.at['B','A'] = .0012
print(df)
df=df*1000
print(df)
print('__2___')
df.loc['B','A']= df.at['B','A'].astype(float)
df.at['B','A'] = .0012
print(df)
df=df*1000
print(df)
print('__3___')
data2 = {'A':[0.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=['B'])
print(df2.dtypes)
print(df2)
df2.at['B','A'] = .0012
print(df2)
df2=df2*1000
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   A    int64
dtype: object
   A
B  0
   A
B  0
   A
B  0
__1___
   A
B  0
   A
B  0
__2___
        A
B  0.0012
     A
B  1.2
__3___
A    float64
dtype: object
     A
B  0.0
     A
B  0.0012
     A
B  1.2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. Trying to used .iloc[] served the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the default used for printing frames by :

```
pandas.set_option("display.precision", 6)
```

Comment: 6 decimal precision is the default. This is unlikely to be the issue